# Connectivity of the space of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I wondered how to prove that the space $C[a,b]$ is connected, but I just can't find where it was written about it. Are there any books or other sources where I could read about this?

Comment: All normed spaces are connected. That's a nice exercise to prove it. Connect each point to the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The space is actually path connected. For $f, g\in C^0([a, b])$, let $\gamma(t) = (1-t)f+tg$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$, with $\gamma(0) = f$ and $\gamma(1) = g$. Addition and scalar multiplication are continuous operations, so $\gamma(t)\in C^0([a, b])$ for all $t$.